# HttpError 400 when requesting on Youtube commentThreads: Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body

Tags: http, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I am tying to access my comments on other videos. But  I didn't understand that what is wrong with the request. I put `youtube.force-ssl` scope.

```
(Pdb) request = self.service.commentThreads().list(part="id,replies,snippet", channelId="UCxz_B5DVTdZV5c0JLctjqUA")
INFO __init__.py line:49 2022-09-19 21:23:55,044 - file_cache is only supported with oauth2client<4.0.0
(Pdb) request.execute()
*** googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id%2Creplies%2Csnippet&channelId=UCxz_B5DVTdZV5c0JLctjqUA&alt=json returned "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.". Details: "[{'message': "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.", 'domain': 'youtube.commentThread', 'reason': 'processingFailure', 'location': 'body', 'locationType': 'other'}]">

(Pdb) request.headers
{'accept': 'application/json', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'user-agent': '(gzip)', 'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/2.52.0 gl-python/3.8.10', 'content-length': '0'}
(Pdb) request.uri
'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id%2Creplies%2Csnippet&channelId=UCxz_B5DVTdZV5c0JLctjqUA&alt=json'
(Pdb) request.body
(Pdb) request.to_json()
'{"uri": "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id%2Creplies%2Csnippet&channelId=UCxz_B5DVTdZV5c0JLctjqUA&alt=json", "method": "GET", "body": null, "headers": {"accept": "application/json", "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate", "user-agent": "(gzip)", "x-goog-api-client": "gdcl/2.52.0 gl-python/3.8.10", "content-length": "0"}, "methodId": "youtube.commentThreads.list", "resumable": null, "response_callbacks": [], "_in_error_state": false, "body_size": 0, "resumable_uri": null, "resumable_progress": 0}'
(Pdb) request.body
```

On the other hand lines below return a valid 200 response.

```
(Pdb) request=self.service.commentThreads().list(part="id,replies,snippet", allThreadsRelatedToChannelId="UCxz_B5DVTdZV5c0JLctjqUA")
INFO __init__.py line:49 2022-09-19 22:06:17,504 - file_cache is only supported with oauth2client<4.0.0
(Pdb) request.execute()
```

I have enabled Youtube Data API and give `youtube.force-ssl` scope again on Google Cloud console but I am not sure that am I have to give any other permissions. According to the doc. `channelId` should be a valid argument but I didn't understand why it returns 400 error if I gave channelId.

Weirdest thing is that even the same example on [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2Creplies%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCAuUUnT6oDeKwE6v1NGQxug%22%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22KYpp7NjFFXk%22%7D) does not work.

[image]

However if I give my channel's id with `allThreadsRelatedToChannelId` argument it returns a HTTP 200 responseas expected.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK YouTube Data API v3 suffers of several bugs, here as `allThreadsRelatedToChannelId` filter gives a superset in comparison with `channelId` filter, you shouldn't have troubles to get the data you are looking for.

Comment: Consider post this issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They had removed `channelId` parameter :( https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247966553